# iPhone app not running on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have my iPhone setup on my computer at home, with my developer account and provisioning profile.

I'm trying to get it setup on my work computer so I can run work apps on it as well.  My work has their own dev account.  I created an app ID and privisioning profile on my personal account and downloaded it on my work computer but its not letting me compile and run on my iPhone.  It says `valid provisiong profile not found on executable.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xCode's organizer > Devices > Provisioning Profiles > Tick Automatic Device Provisioning > Click "Refresh" > Enter Your Developer ID > OK

New provisioning profile will be generated & your iPhone will be included in your developer account automatically.

Comment: I did that, now all my personal profiles show on my work computer.  But I'm getting the same error when running on my device still.

Comment: It says valid signing identy not found next to the provising profile for the app I'm trying to run.

Comment: double check Project Settings. In Code Sign section, make sure "iPhone Developer" (automatic selection) is selected. Try to Clean & Re-build also.

Comment: It also says cannot find valid private key in keychain.

Comment: did you generate any private key in keychain? If not, follow the guide in Provisioning Portal to generate one first.

Comment: Will that interfere with the one on my personal computer?\

Comment: I would rather use the work account, but I can't add my phone's UDID to the profile because there are no more slots left.  Is there still a way to get it working without my UDID on the profile so I don't have to use my profile account at all?